# JOIN every record from A with specific B.id from B where B.id =?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, A and B.

Fields of A: id, name

```
-----------------
 ID |   NAME    |
-----------------
 1  |   name1   |
-----------------
 2  |   name2   |
-----------------
 3  |   name3   |
-----------------
 4  |   name4   |
-----------------
 5  |   name5   |
-----------------
```

Fields of B: bid, id

```
-----------------
 BID    |   ID  |
-----------------
 11     |   1   |
-----------------
 11     |   2   |
-----------------
 12     |   1   |
-----------------
 12     |   2   |
-----------------
 12     |   3   |
-----------------
```

I want to perform a query to show ALL records from A with columns A.id, A.name on the left. And join a third column from B ON id **WHERE bid = '11'**.

So I would have something like this:

```
--------------------------------
 A.ID   |   A.NAME  |   B.BID
--------------------------------
 1      |   name1   |   11
--------------------------------
 2      |   name2   |   11
--------------------------------
 3      |   name3   |
--------------------------------
 4      |   name4   |
--------------------------------
 5      |   name5   |
--------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really name your tables "A" and "B"?

Comment: Ofcourse not! It's for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, B.BID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.BID = yourValue -- use the WHERE clause for additional filtering
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc935/1)

Based on your update, you will want to move the filter from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, IFNULL(B.BID, '') BID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.id = B.id
  and b.bid = 11
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24bbf/5)

Comment: Tried that. I only get the rows where A.id = B.id

Comment: without the WHERE clause, I get all records from A. But B has multiple, different bid records, so it will get overwritten with the bid value of the last row in B.

Comment: @fishbaitfood it is not clear what you are asking.  The query returns your OP.  If that is not what you need then you have to provide more details.

Comment: @fishbaitfood you need to move the `WHERE` syntax to the `JOIN`, see my edit

Comment: Yes, thank you! So simple... Side question: Is there a way to populate the NULL values with an empty string or something?

Comment: @fishbaitfood yes, you will place `IFNULL()` around the field, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

List all values no matter `bid` has a value with `left join`:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.bid
from a
left join b on b.id = a.id
where b.bid = 11
```

Use `inner join` if `bid` has a specific value:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.bid
from a
inner join b on b.id = a.id
where b.bid = 11
```

[Good explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9966/1)

Comment: I still only get the rows where A.id = B.id

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a column in table_B that contains the same value as a.id in table_A? If not, you will not be able to join table_b to table_a. What you need here is

```
WHERE bid = ?
```

Should be something like

```
WHERE bid = a.bid
```

OR

```
WHERE a.ID = b.AID
```